# What were the other injuries to Weasley family members?

Tags: harry-potter

There are nine main Weasleys in the Harry Potter books.  Most of whom got inured in the course of the books.

Arthur:

> attacked by the snake

Bill:

> bitten by werewolf

Fred:

> killed

George:

> ear cursed off

Ron:

> many, including injured during chess, poisoned, affected by brains, etc.

Ginny:

> possessed by Riddle Diary, broken ankle

I can't remember if Molly, Charlie, or Percy suffered any significant injures (obviously cuts and bruises from various confrontations).  Can anyone quote any major injuries to those three?

Comment: I believe that Percy was a prat...

Comment: Is a sprained ankle really a "major" injury? I'm not really seeing a "Weasley" trend here, most people in HP got injured at some point.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - to show just how much the struggle cost the Weasley family.

Comment: I agree with @GorchestopherH. Surely the Potters and the Longbottoms suffered more, haven't they? The Weaselys are just... numerous.

Comment: Molly was traumatized by the Boggart in No. 12 Grimmauld Place while housecleaning (she saw Arthur, her sons, and Harry all dead in succession) and was emotionally scarred from the experience. (OOTP) Charlie Weasley received numerous burns from the dragons he worked with. (PS/SS) I don't recall Percy receiving any major injuries. I'm sure all the Weasleys have at one time or another been bitten by a Garden Gnome, as well. But these are all relatively trivial, although Molly might disagree with me about the Boggart.

Comment: Ron got his feelings hurt in every book.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Charlie had his fair share of cuts, burns and bruises from working with dragons, but as far as I know, that is all

Answer (score 2):

In the Deathly Hallows (**The Goblin's Revenge, page 399**) we see the following statement from Ted Tonks:

> “They’re okay, though?” asked Ted quickly. “I mean, the Weasley don’t need any more of their kids injured, do they?

We can assume that **Charlie**, as a dragon keeper, faced a fairly high level of on-the-job danger, *outside* of his work in the Order - which isn't exactly easy on the body either.

Molly, outside of the cuts and bruises sustained in her everyday quest to be an incredible, if mollycoddling, mother, faced enormous trauma every single time she had to say goodbye to her children. Even saying goodbye to Harry (**The Half Blood Prince**) was a huge pain for her:

> "Promise me you'll look after yourself ... stay out of trouble" (Mrs. Weasley) "I always do, Mrs. Weasley, I like a quiet life, you know me." (Harry Potter)

Imagine what it must be like for a mother to watch your kids leave, possibly to their death!

And as for Percy, imagine the personal trauma *he* must have been going through at the Ministry during their time persecuting Muggleborns - as a Weasley, as someone who knew many Muggleborns and as a person of character! It's like being forced to work at a death camp and supervise the deaths of your friends, family and colleagues!

Answer (score 0):

If you count Ron's old rat, Scabbers (A.K.A. Peter Pettigrew). He had had his hand cut off when bringing Voldemort back, and was likely tortured on several accounts before being killed.

Answer (score 0):

Mrs. Weasley - no injuries I'm aware of

Charlie - none specified, but he worked with dragons so it's safe to assume various scrapes, burns, etc.

Percy - none that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

molly has no physical injures tho she had a lot of bad things happen to her her bogart is members of her family dead so she has moral injury

also for George you forgot the time he almost made Ron make a unbreakable vow and ather slapped him so hard that his rear end was never the same again

Answer (score -1):

**Arthur**

While guarding the Hall of Prophecy for the Order of the Phoenix, Arthur was attacked by Voldemort's snake Nagini; the attack was witnessed by Harry, through his mental connection with the Dark Lord. Critically injured, Arthur was taken to St Mungo's. He survived the attack, but was required to take a Blood-Replenishing Potion at regular intervals. At the suggestion of trainee Healer Augustus Pye, Arthur tried stitches, a Muggle alternative, which Molly did not like. However, the stitches were not effective; Nagini's fangs apparently had a poison that dissolved them. Eventually, an antidote to the poison was found and, he was cured, coming home to find fellow Order members Severus Snape and Sirius Black in the middle of a heated argument. Despite this near death experience.

**Bill**

During the Battle of the Astronomy Tower, Bill was severely injured by the werewolf Fenrir Greyback. Although he wasn't turned into a werewolf, he did develop some wolfish tendencies such as a liking for very rare steaks.
Bill had a pen-pal at a school in Brazil. When his pen-pal wanted him to go on exchange trip, Bill had to decline because his parents could not afford it. His pen-pal, though, was offended and sent him a cursed hat that made his ears shrivel up.

**Fred**

Died in the Hogwarts War

**George**

As a result of an injury from Severus Snape's Sectumsempra during the Battle of the Seven Potters, George is missing his left ear, briefly distinguishing him from his identical twin until Fred's death.

**Ron**

Was splinched when apparating from The Ministry of Magic where Hermione had to act quickly so they wouldn't be caught leaving.   Ron's leg was also injured when Sirius Black attacked him trying to get at Ron's pet rat Scabbars, which was really Peter Petegrew transformed. At one point during this scene, Ron can be heard telling Hermione "They might have to chop it"  in an attempt to impress her with his injury or to gain some sympathy from her.  He was also hurt when playing chess in the first movie where he was sitting on the knight and it was destroyed by the Queen.  He was also poisened by accident.   He was saved by Harry.

**Ginny**

Was at one point, possessed by Tom Riddle in the 2nd book.  She also had a broken ankle.

Comment: This doesn't address Molly, Charlie, or Percy, the ones the question is about.

Comment: The main question was this "What were the other injuries to Weasley family members?"  The statement about Molly, Charlie and Percy was a secondary question to the main question.  I added what I had on the others I didn't think there was a problem with doing that.  No offense but I think I am finished with adding info on this site.  A person can't even attempt to share information without being negatively impacted.

Comment: No, not that I'm downvoting because clearly you didn't understand the "hidden" mark-up and read it.  Now you'll know in the future when you see that - that there is writing there.  The OP answers the question about the others within the context of the question.  Molly, Charlie and Percy injuries are the main thrust of the question.  If you scroll over the boxes, you will see the remaining information there.